# Python self-created package import path

Tags: python

**(Solved)**
This link [https://dev.to/codemouse92/dead-simple-python-project-structure-and-imports-38c6](http://This%20link%20(https://dev.to/codemouse92/dead-simple-python-project-structure-and-imports-38c6)%20explains%20structure%20and%20import%20well.) explains Python structure and imports well, too.

I have created a Python package `test_pkg`.

```
test_pkg/
├── setup.py
└── test_pkg
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    └── sub_pkg
        ├── __init__.py
        └── sub_pkg_a.py
```

In the `main.py`, a module from a sub-package will be imported,
but I have to explicitly write:

```
from test_pkg.sub_pkg import sub_pkg_a
```

Otherwise, if I only write:

```
from sub_pkg import sub_pkg_a
```

Python will report:

```
>>> import test_pkg.main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zheng/tests/test_pkg/test_pkg/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from sub_pkg import sub_pkg_a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sub_pkg'
```

Could you tell me why the package name is required: `test_pkg.sub_pkg`?

The relative import works fine with the package, but if I execute the `main.py` script directly, there will be another import error:

```
~/tests/test_pkg/test_pkg$ python3 main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .sub_pkg import sub_pkg_a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.sub_pkg'; '__main__' is not a package
```

So, the question is: paths of `__init__.sub_pkg` and `__main__.sub_pkg` are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to use here is relative import.

Try running the same thing with

```
from .sub_pkg import sub_pkg_a
```

The dot in this case refers to "relative to the file that import is in", in this case relative to the location of `main.py`

This article explains it pretty nicely https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: If I directly run the script, the relative import does not work. But the explicit import `test_pkg.sub_pkg` works for both situations. Do you know the reason? Thanks

Comment: Relative imports uses the `__name__` attribute to resolve imports. For `__main__` it doesn't have any package information and therefore relative imports are resolved as top level packages in `__main__`.

You can work around this by running it as `python3 -m root_package.main`

Comment: Correction `python3 -m test_pkg.main`

Comment: Thank you very much. The answers are clear and very helpful.